# How do 2 dimentional lists work in Python

Tags: python

I am doing [Project Euler Problem 15](http://projecteuler.net/problem=15). I used the right algorithm, but it didn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
f = [[0] * 21] * 21

# init the list
for i in range(21):
    f[0][i] = 1
    f[i][0] = 1

for i in range(21):
    for j in range(21):
        f[i][j] = f[i-1][j] + f[i][j-1]

print f[20][20]
```

when I finished initializing the list, I printed it. I expected it like `[[1, 1, 1...], [1, 0, 0...]...]`, but it turned `[[1, 1, 1...], [1, 1, 1...]...]` and I can't figure why.

I used to use C-like language and I thought the list in Python is kind of like the array in C, so I used them in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When multiplying a list, you are not creating separate lists but rather create multiple *references* to the *same* list.

Instead, do this:

```
f = [[0 for _ in range(21)] for _ in range(21)]
```

You can see the difference when using the `id()` function:

```
>>> f = [[0]*21]*21
>>> for nested in f[:3]:
...     print id(nested)
... 
4523317152
4523317152
4523317152
>>> f = [[0 for _ in range(21)] for _ in range(21)] 
>>> for nested in f[:3]:
...     print id(nested)
... 
4523317512
4523317440
4523317656
```

Separate objects have separate memory id values, while your lists have the same result for each `id()` call, showing they are all *the same list*.

Comment: @MForever78 great answer that explains why you're getting what you're getting so +1 to Martijn... Hopefully without giving too much away, you can do this pretty much with pen and paper - search for "Pascal's Triangle" and you'll find out what I mean

Comment: @Jon Yeah I do know the math method, but I think I just did the same by programming. The aim to do it is actually to practice Python. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, use this:

```
f = [[0] * 21 for _ in xrange(21)]
```

What you wrote will create a list of length 21 (that's what the inner `[0]*21` does), and then create an outer list which contains the *same* inner list 21 times. This means that whenever you modify an element in the inner list, it is modified in *all* the copies, i.e. in every row of your matrix.

For what it's worth, you might want to check out the `numpy` module (install [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) first of course), which gives you a "proper" n-dimensional array structure.

Comment: Is your way any different with Martijn Pieters? What's the difference between 'xrange' and 'range'?

Comment: @MForever78 in Python 2.x, `range` creates a `list` of the results and `xrange` creates an iterable. In Python 3.x, `xrange` is gone and `range` behaves as `xrange` in Python2.x. So `r = list(range(50))` is required for what `r = range(50)` use to do... (if that makes sense!)